# Is there any way to get session data in folder outside Application folder of Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a folder outside `/application` folder of CodeIgniter called `myfolder`.

My CI application uses Native PHP sessions and it all works fine. CI version is the latest 3.0-development.

I need to access some of the session data in myfolder/myfile.php. If I do a `session_start()` and then `print_r($_SESSION);` then I don't see the session set by CI's session driver. I understand why it doesn't show it.

Do you know any method/hack by which I can refer to session data from the CI's session in myfolder. for example by directly including, say, Codeigniter/libraries/session/drivers/session_native.php or any other file?? I just an array from the session data.

Comment: CI session library doesn't use native session but cookies. You can access cookies but please note that you can also encrypt the sessions in CI.

Comment: @Nish - Yes, It does. Have you checked the latest version (in development)?

Comment: I am sorry for that not knowing about the version in development version. But in the last released version it is mentioned that it doesn't use native PHP sessions. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current [Session_native.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_native.php) doesn't seem to change any of the built in session library's preference or interfere with how the session data is saved, i think the following should work:

- Get a hold of the session id for the session you want to load
- call `session_id($sessid)` with this session id **before** `session_start()`
- call `session_start()`

This should work as long as the various ini settings that control the session lib like [`session.save_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) is the same and maybe (if your host have this extension installed) [suhoshin settings](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#transparent_encryption_options) like [`suhosin.session.cryptdocroot`](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.session.cryptdocroot) doesn't interfere.

Comment: I exactly did the above but seemed not to be working. Let me check again.

Comment: My bad. I was using session_name() to set the ID by mistake. It works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Its a trick but do work. Place this little naughty code just before login redirect. And now you can use `ci_session` with php native session too ,have fun !

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['ci_session'] = $this->session->userdata['ci_session'];
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get in cookeis

```
<?php 

print_r($_COOKIE['ci_session']);
```

Comment: It says "Undefined index: ci_session in ......". My CI's cookie name is ci_session.

Comment: check you may be rename the cookie name in codeigniter. check this file application/config/config.php "sess_cookie_name"

Answer (score 0):

Save the session data which you wants to refer from outside the folder into cookies, which may helps you.

So use cookies to refer data from outside the folder and make sure when you set cookies it should be in proper accessible path