# Codeigniter - unserialize session not working outside application folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to read the session value outside the application folder but it's not working.

My code:

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE['ci_session'])) {
        $uid = unserialize($_COOKIE['ci_session']);
      //passes till here
        if(!empty($uid['uid'])){
            //doesn't get to here
            $userid = $uid['uid'];
        }
    }
```

That doesn't work and I have no idea why.

I have tried this and it works but I can't use this I can only use the above one:

```
   ob_start();
include('index.php');
ob_end_clean();
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->session->userdata('first_name');
```

Do I need to go to my codeigniter config file to allow something? I don't know

Comment: That code is supposed to work? It is a huge security problem. Did you know that `unserialize()` will execute code? You likely don't want that. PHP even had an RFC to try and fix it: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/secure_unserialize#see_also

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208539/is-there-any-way-to-get-session-data-in-folder-outside-application-folder-of-cod