# Access sessions inside codeigniter from external script

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I have following project hierarchy

- /Project

  - /userloginform.php
  - /CodeIgniter

I am setting my session values inside `userloginform.php`.
I want to access these values inside codeIgniter Controller.
I found solution for accessing the session in opposite case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006756/codeigniter-3-access-session-from-outside-codeigniter-installation).

How can I access them inside `codeIgniter`?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

First load library into your codeigniter controller

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

now you can access session object with,

```
$this->session
```

and then get your session data using

```
$this->session->item
```

Here item is the array name or variable name which contains data that i have stored using session.

Answer (score 0):

You can access session value using both way:

`$_SESSION['your_sessioni_key'];` 
`$this->session->userdata('your_session_key');`

First one is regular php format. Second is Condeigniter style. Both will give you same output.

Comment: I tried it this way. This way, I can access the session data set inside codeigniter application. But in my case sessions are set outside the codeIgniter folder

Comment: If you creating the session( outside of codeigniter ) from same base url and same browser then it will accessible in codeigniter also. But if browser or url is different for creating session the you won't get.

Comment: Session is generated on "my-domain.com/app/userloginform" and i am retrieving it here (my-domain.com/app/codeigniter/controller)

Comment: You are doing perfect. Can you print all session. just do print_r($_SESSION) and check

Comment: Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1508844899 ) this is the output i am getting

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Codeigniter reset the `$_SESSION` variable set by `userloginform.php`. Consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208539/is-there-any-way-to-get-session-data-in-folder-outside-application-folder-of-cod).